# PowerShell: Copy Image to Powerpoint from Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, powerpoint

I need to modify a powerpoint presentation with powershell, I have to copy an image from a excel worksheet and paste it into a powerpoint slide.

Any one knows how to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

cls
$pptx = "C:\PowershellScript\CapacityPlan\Report - Performance Contact__template.pptx"
$xslx = "C:\PowershellScript\CapacityPlan\report_capacity_planPO.xlsx"
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $Excel.workbooks.open($xslx)
$Excel.Visible= $true
$worksheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
$range = $worksheet.Graph("Grafico 2")
$range.select()
$range.copy()

## Create an instance of Powerpoint.

$objPPT = New-Object -ComObject Powerpoint.Application
$objPPT.Visible ='Msotrue'

## Add a slide to the presentation.

$project = $objPPT.Presentations.Add()
$slide  = $project.Slides.Add(1, 1)

## Paste the table into the slide.

$shape = $slide.Shapes.Paste()

## Position the table.

$shape.Left = 50
$shape.Top = 150
$shape.Width = 300
$shape.Height = 168
$Excel.close